# ¿Puede indexarse una tabla que en su diseño inicial no hallan sido definido indices mas que las llaves primarias?

Tags: mariadb, indices

Tengo una tabla con registros la cual tiene mas de 22Millones de registros en MariaDB sin embargo he observado que solo se encuentra indexada la llave primaria y las consultas son realizadas tomando condiciones de algunas otras columnas, podría definir nuevos indices sin perder los datos actuales y asi tal vez obtener un mejor rendimiento en las consultas?, si se definen nuevos indices los datos anteriores a este cambio tambien quedaran indexados?. cual es la mejor manera de realizarlo partiendo de estos dato?

Comment: Tu pregunta al final no se corresponde con el título de la pregunta. Se puede? Sí. Cuál es la mejor manera? ESE debió ser el título.

Comment: Es cierto. Muchas gracias. Puedo indexar los datos después de haber sido ingresados los datos sin afectar la información y mejorar la consulta, ¿cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo?